# Installing Windows 10 alongside ubuntu 16.04 and adding to GRUB

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub2, windows

I just got a laptop and I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it as the only OS. Now I want to install and add Windows 10 to GRUB but how do I do that?
I really need some help with installing it without damaging Ubuntu. I already looked at some other answers on this site but they do not work for me.

I need help with:
- installing windows
- adding to grub
- partition

Answer (score 4):

Grub is very easy to repair, even without boot-repair (which needs to installed form a PPA or burned to a self starting disk).

I would not worry too much about Windows10 destroying GRUB. Actually I think it is better to let windows do that and fix it later. The major thing is that you do not let windows format your whole disk and install it into another partition as your Ubuntu. To stay on the safe side I would to the following

- Start Ubuntu and run gparted. If you do not have installed it, install it with software center or maybe quicker with this command in a terminal.
   sudo apt install gparted
  *gparted will anaylyse your disk and show you the partitions with names like 'sda1'. 'sda2' etc. Windows uses a different naming scheme, so you should note down the sizes of the partition and their order. So you can recognise them when the windows installer lists them in the installation process
  *reboot and insert the Windows10 installation medium (disk or usb stick). If you have a newer board with UEFI is might be a bit complicated. You must select the same boot scheme (UEFI or Legacy) as with Ubuntu or your will run into trouble. Usually you can set this in BIOS or if you press the hotkey for boot menu, there are options for the hard disk in UEFI and in UEFI/Legacy mode. Every board manufacture is doing things a bit different. I had very bad times, so I always try to stay with UEFI/Legacy mode where I can.
  *select "custom install", not typical (or whatever it is named). This brings you to a screen where you see the hard disk and you can create a new partition or select an existing one to install Windows. i recommend to create a new partition where you  like it best (I used 100GB) and formatted it to NTFS. The continue installation.
  *Your Windows installer probably ignores your Ubuntu installation and just overwrites Grub with its own loader. You will see it on the first reboot whether or not you see a grub boot menu.

If you see the grub menu it would not have a windows entry. Thats the easy case. Just boot into Ubuntu, open a terminal and enter

```
sudo update-grub
```

That gives you some output. It should include something about your windows installation. Then reinstall grub with the updated information

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Ususally I always install grub on the hard disk, not in the partition. There are many ways how to do it. If you do not know, this should be fine. "dev/sda" is the name of the first hard disk in a linux system. Should you have several disks you might need another name. In that case use gparted to look at the disks and note the correct name. All partitions in a disk are named like that plus a number, e.g. sda1, sda5,.. On the command line you always need the full name with '/dev/...'.

Should you boot into windows only, you need to repair grub with a ubuntu live disk, like the original install CD. Just boot into the CD by selecting "Tying Ubuntu" and not "installing" it. Then your can chroot into the original installation, but that is a bit complicated. Other way is to just enter the two commands above. That will include the live installation but also your original installation. On reboot you select your original installation (you will recognize the partition name, e.g. sda1). Then from Ubuntu, just run the two commands **again**, to remove the live CD entry and make your Ubuntu the default boot entry.

There are other descriptions on this site to make Windows10 the default entry. You should find them easily.

Generally, grub2 is very robust. I never had a problem that could not be solved with a reinstallation of grub.

Answer (score 0):

At first question Do You have one hdd or two separate ?

Remember , first install Windows then install Linux, if you use this way it make less problems.

In first case:

You can try install windows on one of You partitions where You don't have Ubuntu. Unfortunately when computer will restart You get Ubuntu welcome screen not windows. Now to repair grub you Can use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) i have hope this program resolve problem with boot.

In Second case :

You can install windows on another disk then chance boot sequence using for example

> EasyUEFI_Free

boot from another disk using F12.
or using msconfig and Boot tab but i don't recommend it for you if You are not advanced user.

Or If You really need windows and you can not format You actual system/drive. You may install virtual box and using Windows on VM.

Also a very handy program to have:
[Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer i dont know if i have 1 or 2 hdd how can i check? i tried with Windows first but it did not really work so i just installed full Ubuntu.

Comment: You can disassemble Your laptop and check or use crystaldiskinfo. You can Install first windows then install Ubuntu. Ubuntu have option "Install Ubuntu  alongside  Windows "or something like that, and all will do practically automatic

Comment: Hi! i tried with ubuntu alongside windows but the option was ot there so i made an full install

Comment: What mean "ot there" ? , so try do it manula. If you have one disk. First install Windows then install grub on /sda and Linux system on different partition than windows . If you have UEFI Bios you need create  linux iso for UEFI using rufus. Then if will be work. And all install on one disk.